# Google Charts Add data from PHP Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I am trying to generate google charts using PHP and ajax.

my php file is returning values as bellow

```
["India":149,"United States":1375,"Taiwan":22,"Latvia":1,"New Zealand":2,"Argentina":1,"Namibia":4,"Ghana":4,"Mauritania":1,"Sudan":3,"Kazakhstan":2,"Nigeria":3,"Kenya":2,"FYROM":1,"Nepal":4}]
```

into vribale

> jsonData

i am trying to add these values in Google Charts with bellow code

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

its giving error as i assume that there is no Colums define in value. so i change code to bellow

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data.addRows(jsonData);
```

this is also giving me error that value must be array.

how to fix this, as i can't change result from PHP file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must restructure your jsonData before creating your chart instance.
If you have 2 columns, you need to transform json into array of array, in your case it'll look like:

> [["India",149],["United States",1375], ....["Nepal":4]]

Try this:

```js
var chartData = [];
for(var i in jsonData[0])
{
    chartData.push([i, jsonData[0][i]]);//This create ["Key", Value] for each value in jsonData
}

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data.addRows(chartData);
```

Hope this help

EDIT 1:
Your jsonData variable is not valid, did you pasted it okay?
It might be an associative array? Like { "India" : 123, "Argentina" : 456 } ?
My example work with associative array, so it is not tell me.

EDIT 2:
You must add [0] to jsonData, because it is an array of an associative array. Try it now.

EDIT 3:
Here is the code working. https://jsfiddle.net/wp0kLmj5/

Comment: Hello @niboc thanks for reply but its not working, first error is missing ] in loop and other is this output of console.log(chartData);  [["0", "["], ["1", "{"], ["2", """] ....

Comment: Can you paste your jsonData as it was returned?

Comment: [{"India":149,"United States":1375,"Taiwan":22,"Pakistan":21,"Slovak Republic":7,"Cambodia":1,"Macau":1,"Estonia":1,"Latvia":1,"New Zealand":2,"Argentina":1,"Namibia":4,"Ghana":4,"Mauritania":1,"Sudan":3,"Kazakhstan":2,"Nigeria":3,"Kenya":2,"FYROM":1,"Nepal":4}]

Comment: Hello @niboc if you see in above data, first value is country name and second is value.

Comment: Code Edited. Try now please.

Comment: Hello @ niboc  sorry but its not working. now value of chartData is  [["0", "["]]

Comment: Yes, i just notice and edited again, try now. It was my fault, sintax problem.

Comment: I copy and paste your jsonData and it has some unkown chars. It seem to be the problem, you need to clear it first.

[{"India":149,"United States":1375,"Taiwan":22,"Pakistan":21,"Slovak Republic":7,"Cambodia":1,"Macau":1,"Estonia":1,"Latvia":1,"N??ew Zealand":2,"Argentina":1,"Namibia":4,"Ghana":4,"Mauritania":??1,"Sudan":3,"Kazakhs??tan":2,"Nigeria":3,"??Kenya":2,"FYROM":1,"??Nepal":4}]